# Get all email message using Microsoft Graph API in c#

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I have the following functions to get messages using Graph API

```
var client = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);
var messages = await client.Users["useer@domain.com"].Messages
     .Request()
     .GetAsync();
```

I am only able to get the latest 10 messages. How do I get all the messages? I tried to have a look at the microsoft documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp but unable to find any clues.

Comment: not the answer I am looking for. I have put a c# code not a URL one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer after googling and trial error.

```
IUserMessagesCollectionPage msgs = await _client.Users[user@domain.com].Messages.Request()
                .Filter("put your filter here")
                .GetAsync();
            List<Message> messages = new List<Message>();
            messages.AddRange(msgs.CurrentPage);
            while (msgs.NextPageRequest != null)
            {
                msgs = await msgs.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
                messages.AddRange(msgs.CurrentPage);
            }
```

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer with one caveat.  It needs to save the state of msgs or will be stuck in an infinite loop.

needs to be
msgs = await msgs.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();

Comment: And how do you filter? what is the syntax for it? I can't find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `.Top()`:

```
var client = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);
var messages = await client.Users["user@domain.com"].Messages
     .Request()
     .Top(100)
     .GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp):

Depending on the page size and mailbox data, getting messages from a mailbox can incur multiple requests. The default page size is 10 messages. To get the next page of messages, simply apply the entire URL returned in `@odata.nextLink` to the next get-messages request. This URL includes any query parameters you may have specified in the initial request.