# Get all messages in Outlook using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I have a question about Microsoft Graph API for C# code. Is it possible to get all messages which I have in Outlook?

I found a good article, but I'm still not getting an answer to my question. The article:

[Get all email message using Microsoft Graph API in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64455925/get-all-email-message-using-microsoft-graph-api-in-c-sharp)

(UPDATED) I found a good video about how to connect to Microsoft Graph: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=acnFrkBL1kE&ab_channel=Microsoft365Developer

I have still the same question. I can get 1000 emails for call. Is there any way to get all messages from my Outlook? They should be from all my folders.

My new code for call 1000 messages:

```
public async Task<(IEnumerable<Message> Messages, string NextLink)> GetUserMessagesPage(
        string nextPageLink = null, int top = 1000)
    {
        IUserMessagesCollectionPage pagedMessages;

        if(nextPageLink == null)
        {
                pagedMessages = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Messages.Request().Select(msg => new
                {
                    msg.Subject,
                    msg.BodyPreview,
                    msg.ReceivedDateTime
                }).OrderBy("receivedDateTime desc").Top(1000).GetAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            var messagesCollectionRequest = new UserMessagesCollectionRequest(nextPageLink, _graphServiceClient, null);
            pagedMessages = await messagesCollectionRequest.GetAsync();
        }
        return (Messages: pagedMessages, NextLink: GetNextLink(pagedMessages));
    }
```

(UPDATED) I have tried also this:

```
pagedMessages = await _graphServiceClient.Users["email@.com"].Messages.Request().Select(msg => new { msg.Subject}).Top(1000).GetAsync();

                messages.AddRange(pagedMessages.CurrentPage);
                while (pagedMessages.NextPageRequest != null)
                {
                    pagedMessages = await pagedMessages.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
                    messages.AddRange(pagedMessages.CurrentPage);
                }
```

It was mentioned here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/main/api-reference/beta/api/user-list-messages.md

Comment: how does your question differ from the one you linked?

Comment: Have you checked the [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions)?

Comment: @FalcoAlexander the thing is that he answered his question, but this answer is not working for me, and also can not find any good documentation from Microsoft about it in C# code.

Comment: can you share any error msg / responses when you actually request?

Comment: @FalcoAlexander the problem is that I'm not getting an error for this, I'm just getting null. I think I found the mistake in portal.azure, I should give permission for it.

Answer (score 1):

From: [Microsoft Graph REST API - Get message Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)

> There are two scenarios where an app can get a message in another
> user's mail folder:
>
> - If the app has application permissions, or,
> - If the app has the    appropriate delegated permissions from one user, and another user has    shared a mail folder with that user, or,
>   has given delegated access    to that user. See [details and an
>   example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-share-messages-folders).
>
> ### Permissions
>
> One of the following permissions is required to call this API. To
> learn more, including how to choose permissions, see
> [Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference).
>
> 1. **Delegated (work or school account)** - Permissions: Mail.ReadBasic, Mail.Read
> 2. **Delegated (personal Microsoft account)** - Permissions: Mail.ReadBasic, Mail.Read
> 3. **Application** - Permissions: Mail.ReadBasic.All, Mail.Read

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have updated my answer and added more information about permission, but still can not get any messages from my Outlook.

Comment: @FredericoEglesias - It looks like you code requires application permissions, unless you are handling the delegation?

Comment: I tried to use this code: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-dotnet, but still, I'm getting an error and I also updated my post more. I have a status that is waitingForActivation.