# Get All Email Messages with Microsoft Graph - version 5.2.0 or above

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

The original code that I have is:

```
   var messages = await graphClient.Users["user@domain.com"].MailFolders[folderName].Messages.GetAsync();
```

And I'm using Microsoft.Graph 5.2.0.
Unfortunately, this only returns 10 emails at a time.

I tried the code that was posted to answer this question: [Get all email message using Microsoft Graph API in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64455925/get-all-email-message-using-microsoft-graph-api-in-c-sharp). But, I'm having a problem with .Request method not being available. Here is the code that I am referring to:

```
var client = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);
var messages = await client.Users["user@domain.com"].Messages
     .Request()
     .Top(100)
     .GetAsync();
```

When I code that way. the .Request() is showing red squiggly saying MailFolderItemRequestBuilder does not contain a definition for 'Request'.
Even upgrading to Microsoft.Graph 5.5.0 did not help.

Could someone please help me out?

Comment: I got a response from GitHub to check the upgrade documentation here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#query-parameter-options . So, yes the new syntax would be as posted in the answers below. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2):

In v5 you can specify the page size this way

```
var messages = await graphClient.Users["user@domain.com"]
            .MailFolders[folderName]
            .Messages
            .GetAsync(x =>
            {
                x.QueryParameters.Top = 100;
            });
```

Other query options like `Select`, `Filter`, etc. are set with similar code.

Resources:

[Query parameter options](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#query-parameter-options)

Answer (score 1):

In v5 the syntax has [changed](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md). The correct code to get the *first page* of messages in v5.x would be:

```
var page = await graphServiceClient
    .Users[userId]
    .MailFolders[folderName]
    .Messages
    .GetAsync(config => config.QueryParameters.Top = 50);
```

The type of the return value `page` is `MessageCollectionResponse`. This has a property `OdataNextLink` which points to the next page of messages. To [iterate through all available pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/paging?tabs=csharp) of messages you could use the following extension method:

```
public static async Task<IReadOnlyList<Message>> GetAll(this Task<MessageCollectionResponse> collectionTask, GraphServiceClient serviceClient, int maxCount = int.MaxValue)
{
    if (collectionTask == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(collectionTask));

    var response = await collectionTask;
    var items = new List<Message>();

    var iterator = PageIterator<Message, MessageCollectionResponse>.CreatePageIterator(serviceClient, response,
        item => { items.Add(item); return items.Count < maxCount; });

    await iterator.IterateAsync();

    return items;
}
```

This will allow to adopt the code example as follows:

```
var page = await graphServiceClient
    .Users[userId]
    .MailFolders[folderName]
    .Messages
    .GetAsync()
    .GetAll(/*500*/);
```

This approach can be taken by any `.GetAsync()` call within the Graph SDK that returns an `CollectionResponse`. Unfortunately it is not possible to write the above extension method in a generic way, cause the collection base type doesn't give any hint about the element type of the collection (or we have to use reflection). So for every collection response you like to iterate you have to copy/paste the above `.GetAll()` method and replace the types accordingly (e.g. replace `Message` with `User`).

Also depending on your use case you have to decide if you set the `Top` parameter within the `.GetAsync()` call or provide the desired number in the `.GetAll()` call. The difference in both approaches is how many requests you want to send to graph and how many entries each of these requests should return. Also be aware that the `Top` parameter has a documented max value (mostly 999). If you need / expect more elements than this number you have to use `.GetAll()`. In all other cases it depends on how lazy you process the data.